# Populate a 5 * 5 list with python

Tags: python, list

I have a list[5][5] to populate... it looks like a table with 5 columns and 5 rows.
Each cell can be either one or zero.
I want to find different 2^25 possibility that can exist. Each possiblity is a combination of either 0 or 1 in a 5*5 table/list

How can I do that? With nested loop or something?

Comment: How can I do that? With nested loop or something?

Comment: Do you want to draw *all* 33,554,432 5x5 tables?

Comment: I think he is looking for permutations, but the homework instructions didnt use that word.

Comment: #johnsyweb in some way, (it doesn't have to printed physically), I just want to have 33,554,432 of 5x5 tables in a list

Comment: @Felix, some meaningless homework..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you start small... with a 1x1 `list` first and check that you can display both of the available combinations:

```
[[0]]
[[1]]
```

Next up, try a 2x2 `list`. There are 16 different `list`s to display:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1]]
[[0, 0], [1, 0]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1]]
[[0, 1], [0, 0]]
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
[[0, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [0, 0]]
[[1, 1], [0, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

If you've got the algorithm right for 1x1 and 2x2, then you should be able to generalise it to print your 5x5.

Good luck!

### Update

Since you appear to be still struggling, here's a little extra help.

Break this problem into smaller problems. I'd start with generating the values. If you ignore the `list` notation in my examples above, you'll see that the sequence of values is one that is recognisable to every computer scientist on the planet. It's also pretty easy to generate in Python using [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bin) and [`str.zfill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill).

The second problem is putting them into `list`s. This isn't too hard either. Supposing the first value in your sequence is '0000'. You know that your `list`s are two rows by two columns. You can put the first two characters into a list and put that list into a list. Then put the next two characters into a list and append that list to the previous one. Done. Repeat for each value in the sequence.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import itertools
gen = itertools.product((0,1),repeat=25)
```

To create a generator to get all of the combinations in 1d and then reshape the data as needed.

Comment: I would just append `xrange(2**25)` into a list and unpack the bits... Each number is a 5x5 array, packed in binary format

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion.